# Game freezes when writing code to delay game?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I'm making a game and I currently have this code

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False
    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3
class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.started = False
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Button-1>', self.start_game)
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0
    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2
    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2
    def start_game(self, evt):
        self.started = True
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Bounce")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()
paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')
while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False and paddle.started == True:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
tk.update_idletasks()
tk.update()
time.sleep(0.01)
```

However, when I run the module, nothing will show on the canvas, but there's no error. I click on the canvas, the canvas freezes, and then I'm forced to close it. I've tried it multiple times and nothing is working. I need help knowing if there's a bug that's causing it to freeze

Comment: your whilelloop blocks the mainloop. Why you need that whieloop?

Comment: Its never really a good idea to use `time.sleep()` with tkinter as it freezes the app, tho here the problem could be your infinity loop.

Answer (score 1):

`paddle.started` is never set to `True`, meaning the code in your if statement on line 70 is never run, and the while loop loops indefinitely without doing anything.

As a side-note, tkinter is for making GUI applications, not games, and making games using it is more hassle than it's worth. I'd suggest looking into pygame: https://www.pygame.org/